# How can I use Pixel Perfect Camera and Ripple Effect Shader at the same time in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, pixel

For the Ripple Effect Shader I'm using this: https://github.com/keijiro/RippleEffect

This Shader worked fine until I had to change the **Scriptable Render Pipeline Settings** to URP so I could use the Pixel Perfect Camera from Unity. Now the shader doesn't work. Any hints to why this is?

I tried to follow this tutorial right here but for some reason he didn't encounter the problem I did:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STyY26a_dPY *starts at 3:40*

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, apparently I was using the URP Pixel Perfect Camera instead of the CineMachine Perfect Camera, it all works now